# recurring notification statement after checking a condition in python

Tags: python

I am working on a small proof of concept and using python to illustrate the idea. The idea is the program will run in a loop and will check for input. Now if the input falls under a threshold then it sends a notification. But I am trying to restrict the notification at an interval of 4 sec. And thats where I am loosing either with the logic or with some syntax. Either way It is doing some unexpected things

1: keep on entering 0 and it will display the below threshold message until it reaches a 4 sec mark and then it just prints out the message 4 times in a single line. I want them to show after every 4 seconds. The idea is (A)the input might change in that 4 sec and the notification switches. (B)I want the notification to play out as a reminder with a recurrence of 4 sec every time the script hits the condition if weightIn < 0.5..if it is true then the notification goes out after 4 sec from the first time it was sent

Sorry if I tried over explaining it. I am pretty new to python

```
import threading
def main():
        while True:
                weightIn = float(input("Get value: "))
                threshold = .5

                def operation():
                        if weightIn < 0.5:
                                #send notification at an interval of 4 sec
                                threading.Timer(4.0, operation).start()
                                print("Below weight threshhold...send notification")
                        else:
                                print("You are good")

                if threshold is not None:
                    operation()

main()
```

Comment: For the time, I would recommend polling and timeit, which is a module that should be imported. timeit is the module, that is. Polling is a concept.

Answer (score 1):

First avoid declaring functions in a loop. Then ask yourself, if an object would not be appropriate, because it properly encloses state attributes.

But for the algorithmic part, it is simple (if I have correctly understood the problem ...). Store the timestamp of last notification and send a new one if more the 4 seconds have elapsed. In pseudo-code :

```
last_notification_time = 0
threshold = 0.5
loop:
    weighIn = get_new_value()
    if weightIn < threshold:
        time = get_time_in_seconds()
        if (time > last_notification_time + 4):
            last_notification_time = time
            send_notification()
    # actual processing
```

In Python, it could look like :

```
#import time

def main():
    last_notification_time = 0
    threshold = 0.5
    while True:
        weighIn = float(input("Get value: "))
        if weightIn < threshold:
            cur_time = time.time()
            if (cur_time > last_notification_time + 4):
                last_notification_time = time
                print("Below weight threshhold...send notification")
        # actual processing

main()
```

Comment: @Serge--agreed about not declaring a function inside a loop...embarrassing I actually did that. I see your point about reading time stamp...which totally works!! thanks again for the direction.